# How to create tree structure from html element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion, treeview, recursive-query

this is my element in my vue2 application:

```
<div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
    <div>
        <div entity-type="entitytype1" type="elementType" id="2" class="single-element"></div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype2" type="elementType" id="59" class="single-element"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div entity-type="measures" type="elementType" id="3" class="single-element"></div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="13" class="single-element"></div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype2" type="elementType" id="14" class="single-element"></div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="11" class="single-element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="12" class="single-element">
                </div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get a tree structure with the id's of single-element and I am using this function to get this hierarchy view:

```
   buildDraggedHierarchy(el) {
            if (!el) {
                return [];
            }

            const children = [...el.querySelectorAll(":scope>div")];
            const output = children.map((child) => ({
                id: child.querySelector(".single-element") ? child.querySelector(".plan-element").id : null, 
                type: child.getAttribute("type"), 
                children: this.buildDraggedHierarchy(child.querySelector(".draggable-container")), 
            }));

            return output;
        },
```

but output comes like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "59",
                "type": null,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "13",
                "type": null,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "type": null,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "type": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "type": null,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

so the last element's children doesnt come correct. I would expect the children comes with and id 12 instead id doesnt shown at all. how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- Your function only executes a `return` statement when the argument is falsy (the base case), but not in the other cases. The assignment to `output` is not very useful, as this variable is immediately freed after assignment. Instead *return* what you assign to `output`.
- The `child` element is not the one that has the `id` and `type`. It sits one level deeper, so a selector is needed for that.

Here's the fix:

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".child-elements-container");
const elementHierarchy = this.buildDraggedHierarchy(element);
console.log(elementHierarchy);

function buildDraggedHierarchy(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return [];
    }
    let children = [...el.querySelectorAll(":scope>div")];
    return children.map((child) => {
        const elem = child.querySelector(".single-element");
        return {
            id: elem.id,
            type: elem.getAttribute("type"),
            children: this.buildDraggedHierarchy(child.querySelector(".draggable-container")),
        };
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
    <div>
        <div entity-type="entitytype1" type="elementType" id="2" class="single-element"></div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype2" type="elementType" id="59" class="single-element"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div entity-type="measures" type="elementType" id="3" class="single-element"></div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="13" class="single-element"></div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype2" type="elementType" id="14" class="single-element"></div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="11" class="single-element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container">
            <div>
                <div entity-type="entitytype3" type="elementType" id="12" class="single-element">
                </div>
                <div class="child-elements-container draggable-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```